# Meta transactions on ethereum

Tags: solidity, web3js, transactions, ether, meta-transactions

I've been trying to implement meta transactions in my project, but I couldn't find anything, openzeppelin's documentation wouldn't work

I need a tutorial from A to Z because I'm still a beginner.

can you please provide me with any tutorials or articles that can help me?

thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta transactions are a tricky topic for beginners but kudos for going for it. OpenZeppelin is no longer maintaining Gas Station Network. Check opengsn documentation for latest version.

Github: https://github.com/opengsn/gsn/releases

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I'll check it out